# After filling holes, the fill seems to be separate?

Tags: mesh

I havent ever had this happen before and cant figure out a solution. I did some grid fill in a helmet pattern and although it doesnt show up as a separate mesh, its acting like it for some reason. I have tried a bunch of options but the fill being a different color is making it act as a separate mesh outside of blender. Anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The vertices might not be merged.
Can you try selecting all vertices and hit "Alt + M" and "Merge by Distance"?

Comment: maybe recalculate the normals? alt N

Comment: Problem is, I tried both of these things. Nothing has worked. I use merge by distance almost all the time and the normals WERE flipped but I corrected that and it still changed nothing.. 